# Jquery wait for all same classess to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am having a problem related to **jQuery** as when button is clicked the angular loads the html with same classes which are ".fc-title". how can i make sure to wait for all these classes to appear and then perform a click function

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at `.load()`?

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```
$('.fc-title').load(function(){ alert("they are all loaded"); });
```

Comment: yeah i did but didnt worked in my case even ready didnt worked for me too

Comment: well. tell me why?

Comment: i m using casperjs for automation and i m using jquery in its evaluate function i am waiting for certain text to appear and then perform a click function on it and these text have same classes when it loads from angular

Comment: okay. this is a site where you show code and explain your problem, if you wont show the code, you wont get help.

Comment: yeah i know i just wanted to know is there a way to wait for all classes to appear in jquery and then perform functions on it ? please help me out

Comment: dude, It's in my answer. it works. can't tell you anything more.